# dividing binomial coefficient by a number

Tags: binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, factorial

so, the question is as follows :

find the remainder when
$${}^{119}C_{33}$$ is divided by $5$

my approach:
well, I don't know about any method except for writing  $${}^{119}C_{33} =  264987608114625679810381761543$$
now it is easy to see that the remainder on dividing this by $5$ should be $3$.
so,is there a better method to get to the solution? kindly help me out.

note: I saw a similar variation of this question at MSE but it had a special case where in
${}^{n}C_{k} , n! = (n-k)!$ hence I hope this qualifies as a new question.

Comment: What is the formula for ${}^{n}C_{k}$ ??

Comment: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680/Parsons/MVP6690/Essay1/mod5.html

Comment: The usual notation is $\binom{119}{33}$.

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari if you have another question, ask it elsewhere rather than in the comments.  Regardless, read about binomial coefficients [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: @JMoravitz Why not formulate the idea as an answer ?

Comment: [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)

Comment: @Peter because the idea is not mine and I put absolutely no effort into understanding it beyond knowing that it will lead to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Robert Israel's recommendation in the comments to use Lucas's theorem. Here's the computation:
\begin{align*}
119_{10} &= 434_5,\\
33_{10} &= 113_5.
\end{align*}
Then Lucas tells us that
$$\binom{119}{33}\equiv\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{3}\equiv 4\cdot 3\cdot 4 \equiv 3\pmod{5}.$$

Answer (score 2):

For $m\in \Bbb N$, let
$$ f(m)=\frac{m!}{5^{\lfloor m/5\rfloor}\lfloor m/5\rfloor!}$$
be the product of all numbers $1,\ldots, m$ that are not multiples of $5$. The remainders $\bmod 5$ of the factors are periodic $$1,2,-2,-1,*,1,2,-2,-1,*,\ldots,$$ hence so is $f(m)\bmod 5$ (with period length $10$):
$$\tag11,2,1,-1,-1,-1,-2,-1,1,1, \ldots $$

Now from
$$ {119\choose 33}=\frac{119!}{33!86!}=\frac{119!/5^{23}}{33!/5^6\cdot 86!/5^{17}}=\frac{f(119)}{f(33)f(86)}\cdot\frac{23!}{6!17!}$$
and
$$\frac{23!}{6!17!}=\frac{23!/5^{4}}{6!/5^1\cdot 17!/5^{3}}=\frac{f(23)}{f(6)f(17)}\cdot\frac{4!}{1!3!} $$
we see that we need only find a few values of $f\bmod 5$ by lookup from $(1)$, and  ${4\choose 3}\bmod 5$.